# C Realloc Memory

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I need to memorize how much memory I allocated with realloc().
Help me
       if(!array)

```
    array=(Type*) calloc(1,sizeof(Type));

else

    array=(Type*)realloc(array,(cont+1)*sizeof(Type));    



array[cont].setName(....);


cont++;
```

It doesn't work: after firt insert, it say: Access violation
I initialized the cont = 0 in the constructor of my class and freed memory in the destructor.

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector`?

Comment: please provide a [MCVE]. What is `c`,`array` and `Type` ?

Comment: Please elaborate. *It doesn't work* doesn't explain what the problems are.

Comment: `realloc(array,count*sizeof(Type*));` --> `realloc(array,count*sizeof(Type));`  (drop *)  (also in `calloc()`)

Comment: @toby303 I created 'c' instances of registry. this 'array' is the registries array, formed by name, surname, age .....The version with calloc works ... now I need to implement with realloc....

Comment: @R Sahu It say ACCESS VIOLATION. It doesn't insert into my array

Comment: I need to keep much memory I allocated and reallocate each time.

Comment: @chux I drop * ...it doesn't work

Comment: @Agata code is not even allocating the _correct_ amount of memroy.  To "keep how much memory", allocate a larger block and store the count in that block.

Comment: @chux I'm beginner with dynamic memory. Help me

Comment: @Agata Re-post after reading and following [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926184/c-realloc-memory?noredirect=1#comment63302959_37926184).  "It doesn't work." is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments added to your code:

```
int count=0;
if(!array)
    array=(Type*) calloc(count,sizeof(Type*);  // Problem:
                                               // missing )
                                               // use sizeof(Type)
                                               // calling calloc with count being zero
                                               // so you do not allocate any memory
                                               // use 1 instead of count

array[c].setName(EditName->Text);
c++;
count++;
array=(Type*)realloc(array,count*sizeof(Type*));  // Problem:
                                                  // use sizeof(Type)
```

so it should look:

```
int count=0;
if(!array)
    array=(Type*) calloc(1,sizeof(Type));

array[c].setName(EditName->Text);
c++;
count++;
array=(Type*)realloc(array,count*sizeof(Type));
```

The variable `c` must be initialized to zero before running this code

Likewise `array` must be `nullptr` before running this code

**EDIT**

There seem to be one more problem if you intend to run this code several times (which I assume you do).

This line:

```
 array=(Type*)realloc(array,count*sizeof(Type));
                            ^^^^^
              Don't use count here as you always sets count to zero
```

The line shall be:

```
array=(Type*)realloc(array,c*sizeof(Type));
```

In general there seems to be no real use of `count`

Comment: It doesn' t work equally

Comment: Same problem? How is `c` initialized? It should be zero.

Comment: @4386427 Yes, int c=0;

Comment: @chux , yes I understand it....Before, with calloc, I did : if(!array) array=(Type*) calloc(3,sizeof(Type)) , because my array to be size 3, but now I do it with realloc().

Comment: Cast not needed in C.  Better to use `array= calloc(1,sizeof *array);` than `array=(Type*) calloc(1,sizeof(Type));`.  Less chance to code wrong, easier to maintain and review.

Comment: @Agata did you also initialize `array` to `nullptr` ?

Comment: @Agata - see working example here http://ideone.com/v0VqZI

Comment: I try:     if(!array)
        array=(Type*) calloc(1,sizeof(Type)); else array=(Type*)realloc(array,(count+1)*sizeof(Type));     and then array[i].setName(...) c++;count++; It doesn t work:access violation after first insert

Comment: @Agata - see updated answer. You don't need `count` at all.

Comment: @4386427 I see that :) It does not solve my problems.

Comment: @Agata - do you have this code inside a function that you call to add new elements?

Comment: @4386427 Yes I do it in createRegistry() function...Do you give me your email? I send you a photo of code (The code is on pc offline)

Comment: See http://ideone.com/ocLn1n for a version where the code is in a function

Comment: You can add a picture to your question - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: @4386427 i don't find button for updating images...give me your mail in private please

Comment: I solved it by myself ... The problem was that I used AnsiString, have changed using char * and go.